# Is it possible to have an extra key modifier?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, modifier-keys

Most windows applications only accept a combination of a key with one regular modifier (Alt, Ctrl, Super and Shift keys). e.g. you cannot define a shortcut as "CapsLock+A".

I need the have an extra modifier to define further shortcuts on my IDE. Using AHK you can use any key as a modifier to map the combination to other keys. However, I need to map a key (e.g. the menu key) to another modifier that other apps cans accept. I hope that [AltGr may work](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#modifier), but apparently it's just an alias for right alt in AHK. (not sure if in the keyboards wit hand hardware AltGr, that key is sending the same signal as right Alt).

So what is your solution to add an extra modifier by mapping another key if possible?

Comment: Do you mean "I need to map a key (e.g. the menu key) to another modifier that other apps **can't** accept" ?

Comment: @user3419297 no